# Remove session entries in redis upon cookie deletion on the user side

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I have the following scenario:

A user logs in, a session entry via [connect-redis](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis) which is valid for 2 weeks. The user can now access certain parts of the app using the session id that is stored in the app.

Now, if 1. the user deletes that cookie in the browser (with the session) and 2. logs in again - there are now 2 session entries in Redis associated with the same user, with the older one being obsolete.

What is the best way to deal with such old/obsolete sessions? Should I use a client library for redis, search through all sessions to find the ones that match the info of the currently logging in user (after she potentially manually removed the cookie), and purge these obsolete session; or is there a better way?

Gracias,

nik

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends whether this (user deletes the cookie) is a common scenario and, if it is, whether there's a problem with obsolete cookies in the server.

Two potential "problems" that I can think of are:

1. Security - could the stale cookie be exploited for malicious intent? I do not see how that's possible, but I may be wrong(tm).
2. Storage - are the stale cookies taking too much (RAM) resources? If there's a lot of stale cookies and each cookie is large enough, this could become a problem.

Unless 1 or 2 applies to your use case, I don't see why you'd want to go through the trouble of "manually" cleansing old cookies. Assuming that you're giving a `ttl` value to each session (2 weeks?), outdated cookies would be purged automatically after that period so no extra action is needed to handle these.

Comment: Hi, Itamar, thank you. `I don't see why you'd want to go through the trouble of "manually" cleansing old cookies` - both of the scenarios you mentioned do not really apply in my case. I just thought of cleaning it up :) Muy bien, less hassle :)